# Git build specify branch in same folder

Tags: git

I am trying to build my local folder as following but could not be done.

master 
branchA
branchB
(all 3 branch from same commit)

git checkout branchA -> modify file
git switch branchB -> build/compile branchB

And I build my sources with compiler in branchB.

However, branchA changes are shown.
Is this possible to be done in single folder?
Or it is only possible if I clone the branches into separate folder?

Answer (score 3):

A modification is not in a branch unless it has been committed.

When you modify a file while `branchA` is checked out, it is not part of `branchA` (yet). It's just an uncommitted change it the working copy. When you switch to `branchB`, the modification is still an uncommitted change in the working copy (although you are on `branchB`). If you want `branchA` to have this change you've made  (and hence be distinct from  `branchB`), you'll need to add and commit the file which you have modified into `branchA` before switching to `branchB`.

However, I suspect your workflow has some deeper problems. What exactly do you hope to achieve from switching branches before compiling especially since all  the branches are at the same commit anyway?